# Git: List all directories at the root of repo

Tags: git, version-control

I need a way to list all directories that have ever existed at the root of my repository. I need them from every branch and tag.

For example:
My current repo has 20 directories at the root of the master branch. On our dev branch, there used to be a directory called "lib". This directory has since been deleted. I need a command that lists this "lib" folder, along with all other directories that may-or-may not exist on the current commit of its branch. I need them all.

I've tried "rev-list", but it only seems to give results from the current branch.

Comment: have you tried with `git whatchanged --pretty=oneline --remote` ?

Comment: Not sure I understand. What is "whatchanged" supposed to be?

Comment: He literally means `git whatchanged`. That's actually a good suggestion with a significantly quicker execution than my suggestion, but it does rely on a porcelain command and requires slightly more complicated parsing of the output.

Comment: My mistake. But when I run this command, I get: "fatal: unrecognized argument: --remote".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git cat-file -p` to print the contents of a tree object, and the `commit^{tree}` notation extracts the tree object of a commit, i.e. you can say `git cat-file -p HEAD^{tree}` to list the root directory contents of the current commit. Use `git rev-list --all` to get the SHA-1s of all commits, and filter away anything but tree objects.

```
while read commit ; do
  git cat-file -p $commit^{tree}
done < <(git rev-list --all) | awk '$2 == "tree" { print $4 }' | sort -u
```

If your repository is big you can expect this to take some time. I tried it with git.git (37k commits) and it took about four minutes with a warm cache. If you have directory names with spaces you'll have to adjust the filter.

Comment: Seems to be a syntax error on line 3 right after "done". (I'm using cygwin, if that matters.)

Comment: What shell are you using? Your shell might not like the path substitution (`<(git ...)`). The command work fine on both bash and zsh (on Linux). You can try this instead: `git rev-list --all | while read commit ; do git cat-file -p $commit^{tree} ; done  | awk '$2 == "tree" { print $4 }' | sort -u`.

Comment: I'm using cygwin (git bash, actually). That second command works great, except I get an exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION. It still seems to give pretty complete output, though.